# MySQL and PHP: Inner join and result

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

Here is a mysql request:

```
$requete1  = mysql_query("
      SELECT a.post_id, e.meta_value 
      FROM wp_postmeta as b 
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS a ON b.post_id = a.post_id
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS d ON b.post_id = d.post_id 
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS e ON b.post_id = e.post_id 
      WHERE b.meta_key = '_show_hide_sales' 
      AND b.meta_value = '1'
      AND d.meta_key = '_sold_sales' 
      AND d.meta_value != '3' 
      AND e.meta_key = '_sales_sort_number'              
      ORDER BY CAST(e.meta_value as UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
      LIMIT ".($from-1).", ".($range+1)  
);   

while($resultat1 = mysql_fetch_array($requete1))
{
    $res2= $resultat1['post_id'];   // this one is ok
    $res3= $resultat1['meta_value']; // this one is ambiguous   
};
```

The search on the post_id ($res2) is ok as it is unambiguous.

But there are three possible meta_keys here:

- The one that is related to "_show_hide_sales".
- The one that is related to "_sold_sales".
- The one that is related to "_sales_sort_number".

But how can I get the meta_value ($res3) that is related to the "_sales_sort_number" meta_key?

My SELECT clearly indicates that I want to retrieve the **e.meta_value** which should be associated to the "_sales_sort_number" meta_key but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and results so we can understand how it doesn't work.

Comment: why join same table three times on same id?

Comment: Please extend description with sql query result.